# PHP - a simple class that can't run

Tags: php

I have a class look like below:

```
<?php 
class theGodFather {
    public function do() {
        echo "the movie is nice";
    }
}

$obj = new theGodFather;
echo $theGodFather->do;
```

When run I got the error: syntax error, unexpected T_DO, expecting T_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/classes.php on line 3

what could I possibly did wrong?

Comment: The correct syntax is `$obj->do()`. And it also appears `do` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Note that your function doesn't *return* a value, it echoes it directly. You then echo the return value of the function when you call it. I.e., you should either have the function return a string and then echo that return value, or have the function echo the string and then just make the call without the echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use [*keywords*](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) as names for functions/classes/methods and constants, `do` is one. You can use them as variable names, however.

Answer (score 3):

"do" is a keyword (can be used in a do while loop). Also you're echoing a function that returns nothing, but echoes something in it.

Rename the "do" function to "echoFunction" or whatever name you choose and then
change this:

```
$obj = new theGodFather;
echo $theGodFather->do;
```

to:

```
$obj = new theGodFather;
$obj->echoFunction();
```

The reason you wouldn't call $theGodFather->echoFunction because theGodFather is a class definition, while $obj is an actual instance of the class.  You can have static methods in PHP that you can call without creating a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

you have use do function in class "do" is a keyword of php and you cannot use keyword in function or class

try this

```
class theGodFather 
{
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
        echo 'a default value';
    }
}

$obj = new theGodFather();

//print_r($obj);
echo $obj->displayVar();
```

Answer (score 1):

`do` is a keyword, therefore the interpreter gets very very confused. :(
Choose a different function name and it works!